# How to create conditional rendering per page and content in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My data structure is as follows:

```
{
  "website": {
    "landing": [
      {
        "title": "home",
        "components": [
          {
            "component_type": "c6_navbar",
            "content": "c8_home_navbar"
          },
          {
            "component_type": "c8_bg_img_txt_btn",
            "content": "c8_home"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "title": "pricing",
        "components": [
          {
            "component_type": "c8_bg_img_txt_btn",
            "content": "c8_pricing"
          },
          {
            "component_type": "c8_bg_img_txt_btn",
            "content": "c8_pricing"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "c6_home_navbar": {
      "title": "Home - Lorem ipsum",
      "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      ]
    },
    "c8_home": {
      "title": "Home - Lorem ipsum",
      "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      ]
    },
    "c8_pricing": {
      "title": "Pricing - Lorem ipsum",
      "subtitle": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    },
  }
}
```

Inside the website object, there is a landing page (this is a template page-component) inside this page there are several objects which represent the website pages, for example when the website is loading I want it to be the `"home"` page and load the `"components"` which is a list of components with a specific type of component `"c8_bg_img_txt_btn"` and content for this component `"c8_home"`. When the user clicks on the pricing button the landing page should render the `"pricing"` object and the components in it with the relevant content.

How can this be done with or without the react-router-dom but the address on the browser needs to be changed every time and adding the `/pricing` for example.

I have the following components:

`App.jsx`

```js
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
        {isLoading ? (
            <div>Loading ...</div>
        ) : (
            <div className="App">
              <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/" component={(props) => <Landing data={data} />} />
              <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        )}
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`Landing.jsx`

```js
/* This component is the template page component. 
 * Please ignore the code in it as it is not working with the existing JSON. 
 * I left the code inside intentionally to show what I am doing wrong
*/

import React from 'react';
import BgImgTxtBtn from '../c8_bg_img_txt_btn/BgImgTxtBtn';

const componentMap = {
    c6_navbar: NavBar
    c8_bg_img_txt_btn: BgImgTxtBtn
};

const Landing = (props) => {

    const data = props.data.landing;

    console.log(data);
        const components = data && data.map((component, index) => {
                const ComponentType = componentMap[component.content];
                if(!ComponentType) return null;
                return (
                    <ComponentType key={index} data={{ ...component, content: props.data[component.content] }} />
                );
        });
        return <div>{components}</div>;
}

export default Landing;
```

Let's say that I have the following component with the "Pricing" button in it to trigger the change.

```js
import React from "react";

const NavigationButton = (props) => {

    return (
        <div><a href={'/pricing'}><button>{props.title}</Button></a></div>
    );
}
export default NavigationButton;
```

Comment: You want to change the url or not?

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan it needs to be changed from `localhost:3000` to `localhost:3000/pricing` or example

Comment: Then I think, you can change your landing to with this one,
`<Route path={["pricing", "home"]} component={(props) => <Landing data={data} />} />`
Thus, for pricing or home, it will automatically render the Landing component. Since the landing component has logic inside itself, it automatically goes the target component.

Comment: @HalilİbrahimÖzdoğan your proposal doesn't work

Comment: Then, I have no idea :/